# Using swiftmailer, how to check if an email was sent successfully?

Tags: 8, emails

For example, when Drupal core contact forms fail to send an email for any reason, swiftmailer throws an exception and logs a message. However, I am trying to hook into the process to display appropriate information for my enduser after a contact attempt fail.

For more information drupal contact form does the following to send a message in [MessageForm.php](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.0.x/core/modules/contact/src/MessageForm.php#L222):

```
 $this->mailHandler->sendMailMessages($message, $user);
```

This trigger the  `mailManger->mail` method which only throws an exception if the mail system had any issues. [Here is the relevant code in swiftmailer](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/swiftmailer/-/blob/8.x-2.x/src/Plugin/Mail/SwiftMailer.php#L347)
Is it possible to determine if the mail failed within the the `save` method of MessageForm.php?